# Apache 403 Error Forbidden

Tags: apache2, clickonce, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Apache in Ubuntu server to host ClickOnce Application. Virtual directory was configured on httpd.config file and I also added .htaccess file on /My/Virtual/Directory with following lines

```
AddType application/x-ms-application application
AddType application/x-ms-manifest manifest
AddType application/octet-stream deploy
AddType application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument xps
AddType application/xaml+xml xaml
AddType application/x-ms-xbap xbap
AddType application/x-silverlight-app xap
```

But when i try to access to /My/Virtual/Directory I'm getting 403 error. **"You don't have permission to access /My/Virtual/Directory/publish.htm on this server**. It was working on the first time but later on no more and funny thing is that I still can access to /My/Virtual/Directory/index.html which is located at the same folder like publish.htm file. So i guess it's not matter of user permission-related issue.
There was no httpd file on the appache folder so created one with the following lines.

```
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /MyWWW /home/webserver/Desktop/ftp
</IfModule>

#Setting Derectory for /home/webserver/Desktop/ftp
<Directory "home/webserver/Desktop/ftp">
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Did you check file permissions for the apache user? Did you allow overrides in the httpd.config? You need at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` in order for this .htaccess file to work. Please post the relevant part of your httpd.config.

Comment: The thing is when i open a file, index.html, which is located on the same folder, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by changing the permission of FTP to "022" in vsfpdd.conf file.